# How to stop Firebird SuperClassic (run as application) in Win 7?

Tags: windows, firebird

I run Firebird 2.5.3 SuperClassic as application in Windows 7 64-bit with this command:

```
fb_inet_server -a -m
```

Now, how can I stop/shutdown it from command prompt? I know that I could right-click its icon and choose Shutdown, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to make this a comment, but it looks like based on [this page](http://www.analyticalsystems.com.au/confluence/display/PUB04/Start+and+Stop+Firebird+Server#StartandStopFirebirdServer-ThreewaysofStartingandStoppingFirebirdSuperServer%26ClassicServer.)
the answer is `net stop fb_inet_server`.